# exec-maven-plugin not detecting class in src/main/java

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have a project that fails with:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: app.Main
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$1.run(ExecJavaMojo.java:283)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

It's not detecting anything in src/main/java relative to the pom file. This is in Eclipse. Please help with this. I truly have no clue why it is behaving like this. Other projects execute fine. It throws the same error regardless of any class specified in app or without a package.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no classes in src/main/java. Those go in target/classes. You need to compile *before* running `exec:java`:

```
mvn compile exec:java -Dexec.mainClass=app.Main
```

Comment: I thought that target included compile. :(